# Regex pattern to find all <code></code> blocks even if they have a CSS class

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have the below code in my WordPress functions.php file. Its aim is to check all post content on save to see if `<code></code>` blocks exist and then perform a htmlspecialchars operation on the content inside the tags.

```
// Encode htmlspecialchars when saving posts
function FilterCodeOnSave( $content, $post_id ) {

    // test data
    $textToScan = $content;

    // the regex pattern (case insensitive & multiline)
    $search = "~<code>(.*?)</code>~is";

    // first look for all CODE tags and their content
    preg_match_all($search, $textToScan, $matches);
    //print_r($matches);

    // now replace all the CODE tags and their content with a htmlspecialchars
    foreach($matches[1] as $match){
        $replace = htmlspecialchars($match, ENT_NOQUOTES);
        // now replace the previously found CODE block
        $textToScan = str_replace($match, $replace, $textToScan);
    }

    // output result
    return $textToScan;
}
```

The code works absolutely fine for instances where `<code></code>` blocks have no class. My problem is that I use `<code></code>` tags both with and without CSS classes and I need the htmlspecialchars operation to apply to all code tags whether they have a class or not.

I need to say something like "find <code(with or without anything here)>" so that the search string will find both plain code tags and code tags that have a class, for example `<code class="language-html"></code>`.

Hope this makes sense.

Also, I'm aware regex isn't a recommended solution by many on here so if you have a better way of achieving the outcome then please feel free to suggest.

Many Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your regex to this maybe :

```
$search = "~<code\s[^>]*.(.*?)<\/code>~is";
```

or

```
$search = "~<code\s.*?>(.*?)</code>~is";
```

Comment: I knew this would be simple... PHP newbie here! Thanks again aelor, I'll mark this as the answer when the time limit expires.

Answer (score 1):

What about ?

```
// the regex pattern (case insensitive & multiline)
$search = "~<code.*?>(.*?)</code>~is";
```

Comment: wont work unless you make that `.*` lazy like this `.*?`

Comment: I would Maxime but I don't have enough reputation I'm afraid. Thanks again though.

Comment: @Maxime he means that .*? works, so better correct your answer before someone downvotes it :P